# clusterApply in R: Exit Cluster if one task finished and save return value

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow

I want to abrote the cluster calculation if one task finished (I dont want to wait for the other tasks) and get the return value of the fastest calculation:

```
require(snow)
library(parallel)

tasks = list(
    job1 = function(y, cl){
        EMGMM(y=y, startMy = 0)
    },
    job2 = function(y, cl){
        EMGMM(y=y, startMy = 1)
    },
    job3 = function(y, cl){
        EMGMM(y=y, startMy = 2)
    }
)

cl = makeCluster( length(tasks) )
clusterExport(cl, "dmvnorm") #needed in EMGMM()

res = clusterApply(cl, tasks, function(f) f(y))
```

If I run this, in `res` are stored the 3 results of the three jobs. But I want only the result of the fastes job.

:)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I do not think this is possible.  Nodes work independently of each other, and that leads to the following question.  How do you stop the process on node A if node B finishes, and node B is completely independent of node A? (To my knowledge you can't).

Also it is my understanding that there is a reconciliation process that combines the outputs of all nodes prior to the output of clusterApply, so from your point of view (as the user), the output of all nodes is available to you at the same time, there aren't sequential results.

If there is a particular reason you want to figure out what function is fastest, you could always use RBenchmark or do some simple system.time wraps around the function calls.  There are plenty of examples of RBenchmark on this site

If you are trying to do this discovery using parallel processing, that is not the way to go.

Alternate Solution ::

If your routine is actually to run all three functions and take the output of fastest one and continue, then you could do something like have your function return a list which will include the function's return value and the time it took the function to run, then select the fastest one given that information. In that way you still can run in parallel.

For example -

```
f<-function(x){
    time<-system.time(result<-replicate(5,rnorm(x)))[3]
    list(result, time)
}
f(2)
#result
#[[1]]
#          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
#[1,] -0.774092 0.2368157 0.3985423 0.16720798 -0.3073049
#[2,] -0.544825 1.5665314 1.5249368 0.04576403 -2.2738331
# 
#[[2]]
#elapsed 
#   0.03
```

Not pretty but that's one way to do it.

Comment: thanks for your post. The reason of why I am doing this is: the Function needs different time for different `startMy` (the result is the same). My plan was to calculate with different `startMy` and exit on the first `return()`. --> the Programm seems to be faster. (I dont know wich `startMy` ist the best, it dependent on `y`)

Comment: @Corben I just added an alternate solution. Like I said before, you'll have to wait for all processes to finish, but if you return (value, time) at least you can have a process to select the fastest one upon return.  If one function is always faster than another, then timing outside of parallel would be the way to go

Comment: Is there no way you can run `stopCluster(cl)` when the first worker returns?

Comment: @Spacedman That's the heart of the question proposed. But when would that call be made?  It can't be made before or after clusterApply, so the only option would be to call it within the function you are parallelizing?  Which means you need to define the cluster connection to all the nodes on all the nodes?  This wouldn't change the host environment cluster though, it would only kill the connection variable on the workers.

I'm not an expert by any means so maybe there's an alternate way to do this, but that's my two cents.